# CreateWindow on windows 8 seems to create window too large

Tags: c++, createwindow

I'm calling CreateWindowEx (below) on Windows 8.1 with a size of 1920x1080 (native res) and the resulting window is much larger (maybe 2 times larger).

```
    HWND windowHandle;

    DWORD style = WS_POPUP;
    DWORD exStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;

    RECT rect;
    SetRect(&rect, left, top, right, bottom);
    ::AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, style, false, exStyle); 

    windowHandle =
    ::CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
        title,              //name of the window class
        title,              //title
        style,              //style flags 
        left, top, right - left, bottom - top,
        NULL,               //parent window
        NULL,               //menu
        applicationHandle,  //handle to application (given at WinMain)
        NULL);
```

I've read in the documentation that the size parameters are expected in device units. My hunch is that this is the cause of the issue but I'm finding no documentation on how to convert or specify in the appropriate units or disable it so that I can specify in pixels.

FYI The device is a Surface Pro II.

Comment: Surely that's because your program is not [dpiAware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  So your window automatically gets rescaled to match the DPI of the video adapter, probably set to 150% or higher.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, It was the SetProcessDpiAwareness function I was needing. For anyone arriving from Google I added SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS::PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE) before my call to CreateWindow().

Answer (score 2):

For anyone arriving from Google, I added:

`SetProcessDpiAwareness(PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS::PROCESS_SYSTEM_DPI_AWARE)`
before my call to
`CreateWindow()`

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention which lib to link against but it should be `shcore.lib`.

Comment: From "SetProcessDpiAwareness" doc. "It is recommended that you set the process-default DPI awareness via application manifest" (VS: "Manifest Tools" -> "Input and Output" -> "DPI Awareness")